# How do I establish the differentiability of this function by definition?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, continuity

Given this function

$f(x) = (x^2 + 1)^{\sin(x)} $

How would I establish its differentiability over the entire function? I understand how to establish differentiability at a point $c$, by assessing the limit of the different quotient at $x = c$. But how would I establish the differentiability of the entire function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a plan:

(i) Prove that $x^2+1$ is differentiable.

(ii) Prove that if $\phi(x)$ is differentiable so is $\ln\phi(x)$.

(iii) Prove that $\sin x$ is differentiable.

(iv) Prove that if $\alpha(x)$ and $\beta(x)$ are differentiable so is $\alpha(x)\beta (x)$.

(v) Prove that if $\theta(x)$is differentiable then so is $\exp(\theta(x))$.

Conclude that your function, which is $\exp(\sin(x)\ln(x^2+1))$ is differentiable.

Comment: This is exactly what in my comment!

Comment: Not quite, you say $\ln(f(x))$ is differentiable by the product rule. But I was writing while you were commenting!

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use the definition of derivative, instead you should use a tricky technique:

$\displaystyle f(x)=(1+x^2)^{\sin x} \implies \ln(f(x)) = \ln\left( (1+x^2)^{\sin x} \right) = \sin x \ln(1+x^2)$

$\displaystyle \implies \frac{d}{dx} \ln(f(x)) = \frac{d}{dx} \sin x \ln(1+x^2) \implies \frac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = \cos x \ln(1+x^2) + \sin x \frac{2x}{1+x^2}$

$\displaystyle f'(x)= f(x) \left( \cos x \ln(1+x^2) + \sin x \frac{2x}{1+x^2} \right) = (1+x^2)^{\sin x} \left( \cos x \ln(1+x^2) + \sin x \frac{2x}{1+x^2} \right)$

Comment: You don't seem to have established the differentiability, just calculated what the value of $f'$ will be if it exists.

Comment: I understand that this is how I would find the derivative of g, but does this help establish that g is in fact a differentiable function?

Comment: Let $g(x) = \ln(f(x))$, then as it can be shown $g$ is differentiable by the product rule. Since $h(x)=e^x$ is also differentiable, $(h \omicron g)(x)$ is differentiable by the chain rule. Hence $(h \omicron g)(x) = e^{\ln(f(x))} = f(x)$ is differentiable. Is it okay now?